# BoxCox.lambda not returning same results as fable features

Tags: r, time-series, forecast, fable-r, tsibble

I am comparing the results of the automatic lambda selection function `BoxCox.lambda` from the `forecast` package VS the `fable` package automatic lambda selection `features`

As you can see below, **the two functions did not return the same results**. Moreover, when I apply the `BoxCox.lamda` on a the same data, but once on a ts object and once on vector, the results are different.

Some body can explain me why it behaves like this ?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(lubridate)
library(fable)
library(tsibbledata)

library(forecast)


vic_cafe <- tsibbledata::aus_retail %>%
  filter(
    State == "Victoria",
    Industry == "Cafes, restaurants and catering services"
  ) %>%
  select(Month, Turnover)


lambda_fable <- vic_cafe %>% features(Turnover, guerrero) %>% pull(lambda_guerrero)
lambda_fable
#> [1] 0.1240828

lambda_forecast <- BoxCox.lambda(vic_cafe$Turnover, method = "guerrero")
lambda_forecast
#> [1] 0.02686482

lambda_forecast_ts <- BoxCox.lambda(as.ts(vic_cafe), method = "guerrero")
lambda_forecast_ts
#> [1] 0.1734189
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `feasts::guerrero()` function from uses all of the data available, whereas `forecast::BoxCox.lambda()` ignores data that doesn't fit exactly within the year.

Your `vic_cafe` dataset starts in April, and so the feasts package will group seasons as April-March, but forecast will use January-December and remove the first part of the data.

Some more discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/tidyverts/feasts/issues/114), and I've added a mention of these differences in the documentation: https://github.com/tidyverts/feasts/commit/830fe4095cf6231e7bb179519cddfeadd9cd7531

Comment: Thanks Mitchell. It seems to be very clear now. I understand the difference between `lambda_fable` and `lambda_forecast_ts`. However, my second question still remains open. As per my understanding `lambda_forecast` and `lambda_fable` have to be the same, as `lambda_forecast` is calculated from a numeric vector with no time index (therefore it could not be trimmed, and have to use all the data)?

Comment: The `forecast::BoxCox.lambda()` function will group series by 2 if the seasonal period is < 2. The first use where a vector is provided, it is assumed that the data isn't seasonal (`period = 1`) and so Guerrero's method will be computed on subseries of length 2. When the ts is used, it is seasonal (`period = 12`) and so the subseries have length 12 (January - December).